# Set per request i18n fallbacks in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, mobility

I have a multi-country Rails app. And I need to set per request i18n fallbacks schema. Is it possible and how to achieve this?

UPD

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord
  # String attribute "languages" (array)
end

class CountriesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @country = Country.find params[:id]

    I18n.fallbacks = {
      @country.languages.first => @country.languages.second
    } # This does not work

    render 'show'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us one example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @cesartalves Updated my question.

Comment: Check this https://dzone.com/articles/setting-and-managing-locales-in-rails-i18n

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share your code. How do you want to determine the locale? Base on what the browser tells in the headers? Depending on a URL or path? Configured by the user in a cookie or their profile?

Comment: @spickermann I try to set fallbacks depending on Country record attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenting a bit (with Rails 6), it is possible to change the fallbacks using the Simple (default) backend, but doing so is **not** thread-safe and will likely cause problems if you do it on a per-request basis. It's somewhat counter-intuitive -- setting `I18n.locale` is the documented way to dynamically set locale per request, so it's natural to assume fallbacks would work the same way. However, from the the `i18n` source:

> The *only* configuration value that is not global and scoped to thread
> is :locale.

Even that isn't very clearly worded. But indeed `locale` is defined as an instance variable, and all other configuration attributes are `@@` class variables.

The Rails guide for I18n says that the Simple (default) backend was designed to only do the "simplest thing that could possibly work", but the framework allows for plugging in custom backends that go beyond that. So, the best way for you to achieve your result will be to find (or create) a backend that supports per-request fallbacks in a thread-safe way.

---

For reference, if someone *does* need to change a language fallback outside the initializer (again, that's globally), `fallbacks.map()` does that:

```rb
I18n.fallbacks.map(:ca => :"es-ES")
```

My original answer mentioned fiddling with the `fallback` hash directly, but using `.map()` preserves falling back to the default locale.

Comment: Does i18n simple backend safely support setting fallbacks per request? It there any gotchas with thread safety? If so, why you advise create custom backend?

Comment: I've redone my answer to make things clearer. tldr: no, the simple backend does not support what you want in a thread-safe way.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what rmlockerd said, due to `fallbacks` being a class variable, I recommend you restore your fallbacks after every request just to ensure that you're not accidentally leaking it to other requests in the same server instance. You could do it like so:

```rb
around_action :restore_i18n_fallbacks

# ...

private

def restore_i18n_fallbacks(&action)
  original_fallbacks = I18n.fallbacks
  begin
    action.call
  ensure
    I18n.fallbacks = original_fallbacks
  end
end
```

(Code not tested but should work or be fairly close to working.)

Comment: I does not look as thread safe. If one request changes fallbacks, and while first call, another request sets different fallbacks?

Comment: It probably isn't thread-safe. I did some more research and the rabbit hole goes deeper than you might think: i18n has some things that it treats as thread-safe (see https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/config.rb) by storing it in `Thread.current` – but this has its own share of problems (see https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store). I think your safest bet would be to manually swap out the backend (which is stored in `Thread.current`) per request and inject your fallbacks there. Then you're basically on the same level of thread safety as the rest of i18n.

Comment: I agree. After looking again over the ``i18n`` code, only ``locale`` is treated as non-global. To do what the question is asking seems totally reasonable, but is beyond what the simple backend will do. So, a custom backend is the way to go.